# Zhukovsky function bijective

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $w =  \frac{1}{2}(z+ \frac{1}{z})$
with domain Z = {z ∈ C | Im z > 0, |z| > 1}
and H = {w ∈ C | Im w > 0}

Is the function Zhukovsky function bijective from Z onto H?

I have already demonstrated $w$ to be analytic and maps the set Z to the upper halfplane H

How can I demonstrate bijectivity?

Comment: Given $w\in H$, solve for $z\in Z$ the corresponding quadratic equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform does not mention your factor $\frac12$ (which anyway changes nothing since $H=2H$).